# Using an EmbeddedSolrServer in SolrCloud case

Tags: solr, solrj, solrcloud

I am currently building an application that is load-balanced (externally via Apache), which starts an Solr 4.2 instance (or more specifically a CoreContainer). I want to set up a SolrCloud that spans all the instances of my application (with replicas etc.). I know how to set up these servers with the required Zookeeper ensemble etc.

My question pertains to the way that I interact with the SolrCloud. So here it is:

- my custom application receives a request and upon this request needs to update information in the SolrCloud
- since I started the Solr instance embedded with my application, I could use an EmbeddedSolrServer to interact with the index, but: is this the correct way to interact with the SolrCloud? Or does this approach circumvent the whole clustering approach that Solr takes and I am better off to separate my application from the SolrCloud cluster and use the CloudSolrServer?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

For debugging purposes alone I prefer not to use `EmbeddedSolrServer`. Using the `EmbeddedSolrServer` throws a `LockObtainFailedException` if you try accessing the index in your application and in the admin console at once.

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/EmbeddedSolr

Comment: I basically ended up separating the application, because using the EmbeddedSolrServer, as you pointed out, brings additional disadvantages with it (esp. when it comes to clustering)

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a way to create an **Embedded Solr Cloud** in your application using the **Solr Tests Module**.

```
<!-- Solr Test Framework -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
    <artifactId>solr-test-framework</artifactId>
    <version>6.6.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Check the UT writing by *jaihind213* [here](https://github.com/jaihind213/Embedded-Solr-Cloud/blob/master/src/test/java/embed/solr/cloud/TheTest.java) it very useful.